# Bifurcation Analysis of the Three Dimensional System of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, bifurcation

A dynamical system is defined as follows:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\alpha x(1-y)(1+z)-x^2y$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\beta y(1-z)(1+x)-y^2z$$

$$\frac{dz}{dt}=\gamma z(1-x)(1+y)-z^2x$$

For which set of (kind of) parameters $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$, the system will possess chaos? How can we have an idea about parameters for local stability of the fixed points? How can we have **Bifurcation Analysis** of the parameters?

Comment: Where is this ODE system from? It would be nice to give more background on the equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us compute the equilibria of the system by solving $\dot{X} = F(X) = 0$, where $X = (x,y,z)^\top$. The equilibrium equation rewrites as
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&x \left( \alpha(1-y+z-yz) -xy \right) = 0 \, , \\
&y \left( \beta(1-z+x-zx) -yz \right) = 0 \, , \\
&z \left( \gamma(1-x+y-xy) -zx \right) = 0 \, .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
If $\alpha$, $\beta$ or $\gamma$ is zero, then there are equilibrium lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with expression $x=y=0$, $x=z=0$ or $y=z=0$. Thus, we assume that $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are nonzero. Four equilibria are obtained analytically:

- $x=y=z=0$
- $x=0$, $y=-1$, $z=\frac{\beta}{\beta-1}\quad$ if $\beta\neq 1$
- $x=\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}$, $y=0$, $z=-1\quad$ if $\gamma\neq 1$
- $x=-1$, $y=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}$, $z=0\quad$ if $\alpha\neq 1$

One last equilibrium corresponding to the case $x\neq 0$, $y\neq 0$, $z\neq 0$ must be considered, but it has no analytical expression. It could be obtained by solving numerically
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
& 1-y+z-yz -xy/\alpha = 0 \, , \\
& 1-z+x-zx -yz/\beta = 0 \, , \\
& 1-x+y-xy -zx/\gamma = 0 \, .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Computing the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix $\partial F/\partial X$ at the equilibria, one can detect stable equilibria where all eigenvalues have a negative real part, [Hopf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_bifurcation) bifurcations, [Pitchfork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitchfork_bifurcation) bifurcations, etc. The transition to chaos may be more difficult to analyze, but can be observed numerically for some particular sets of parameters and initial conditions (see e.g. the case of the [Lorenz system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737191/how-to-know-whether-an-ordinary-differential-equation-is-chaotic), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257315/for-what-r-does-the-lorenz-attractor-exist)]).

Comment: The transition to chaos is not so hard to analyze when you know what bifurcations you should look for :) Still it's almost impossible to do analytically except for few theorems where it's known that there could be chaotic behaviour in the vicinity of some point in parameter space.