# Analytical proofs of saddle node, transcritical and pitchfork bifurcation in 3D

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I am seeking a general algorithm to prove the existence of saddle-node, transcritical and pitchfork bifurcation for a 3D model.

Please provide some notes on this topic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i am seeking some general algorithm to show the existence of saddle node bifurcation or any other bifurcation. For example, if you (or anyone) provide some proof for the same in case of Lorenz system that will be also fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general "algorithm" for bifurcation classification. However, several local bifurcations --i.e. bifurcations which can be detected simply through the stability analysis of equilibrium points-- have a *normal form*, which makes it possible for them to be identified (see e.g. [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_theory)]). A typical example on which this method applies is the Lorenz system [[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2257315)].