# What defines a chaotic system?

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, chaos-theory

Suppose I have an equation of motion of some sort. All I know about chaotic systems is that small changes in initial conditions will increase the outcome at $t$ by exceedingly large amounts. My question is, how do we actually prove this? Also, is it necessary for a chaotic system to be chaotic in any coordinate system, or do we have to prove it for every coordinate system?

I'd guess that if a system is chaotic for one set of coordinates, it'll be chaotic for almost every other coordinate system - except for when you specifically choose to fix the equation.

Comment: You can compute the Lyapunov exponent  of your system to see if it is chaotic.

Comment: @citronrose By computing the Lyapunov exponents, you can prove that a dynamical system is *not* chaotic, or that it may have a chance to be chaotic. There are no general tools to prove that a system is chaotic (see e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737191/how-to-know-whether-an-ordinary-differential-equation-is-chaotic)). *Note*: one consequence of the [Poincaré-Bendixson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem) is that chaotic behavior can only arise in continuous dynamical systems whose phase space has 3 or more dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

There is no real agreement on the definition of chaotic continuous dynamical systems (see e.g. [[1]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chaos.html)), other that they can exhibit a chaotic behavior. In other words, chaos is a consequence that is observed for some nonlinear first-order ODE systems, and some sets of initial conditions. A simple and widely used definition of chaotic systems by [R.L. Devaney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_L._Devaney) is that a chaotic system

1. has sensitive dependence on initial conditions
2. is topologically transitive (for any two open sets, some points from one set will eventually hit the other set)
3. its periodic orbits form a dense set

It was found later that 1. is a consequence of 2. and 3.

Of course, this type of dynamics should not be affected by any ($C^1$-diffeomorphic) change of coordinates, or I would be happy if somebody can provide a counter-example.