# Can a system of linear maps be chaotic?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

This a subsequent question to the one I asked regarding linear flows:
[How to show that a finite dimensional linear system of ODEs cannot be chaotic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294631/how-to-show-that-a-finite-dimensional-linear-system-of-odes-cannot-be-chaotic)

Consider the system
$$x_{n+1}=F_x(x_n,y_n,z_n),$$
$$y_{n+1}=F_y(x_n,y_n,z_n),$$
$$z_{n+1}=F_z(x_n,y_n,z_n)$$
where $F_x,F_y,F_z$ are linear in $x_n,y_n,z_n$. For example, the system
$$x_{n+1}=5x_n+y_n+z_n,$$
$$y_{n+1}=2x_n-y_n,$$
$$z_{n+1}=-3z_n+x_n-y_n.$$

Can such a system be chaotic? That is, is the case for such a system of linear maps analogous to the case of linear flows?

Comment: You can translate my answer using the superposition principle to disprove chaos in linear ODEs directly to linear maps.